# tfs personal access code

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have on premise tfs installation version 2015. I want to generate a personal access code

https://roadtoalm.com/2015/07/22/using-personal-access-tokens-to-access-visual-studio-online/

I am following the above link but I don't see any option to add personal code when I click on my profile.

instead I am seeing the following :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you referred is for Visual Studio Team Service, not for a on-premise TFS 2015. TFS 2015 doesn't have this security feature.

In the latest TFS15 RC1, the feature off authenticating access with personal access tokens will be added. Check https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate.

An alternative, you can configure Basic Authentication for TFS 2015.

Comment: It's worth calling out that if you enable Basic Auth, you should configure SSL, as Basic Auth causes credentials to be transmitted in cleartext, including passwords. With SSL, it will be encrypted.

Comment: Cece - Are there any plans to bring the Personal Access Token capability to on-premises TFS?  We have some users that are using TFS with Git repositories from Linux and Docker.  Without a token, they have to bury credentials in the connection string.  A PAT would simplify this and be more secure.  Any information you have would be helpful.  Thanks!